# Why i have to run php artisan passport:install on server after composer install via deploy bot?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I am deploying my laravel project on server with deploy bot.
These below commands i run on server after pull request

> `chmod -R 777 $RELEASE/storage`
>
> `composer install --no-progress --optimize-autoloader`
>
> `php artisan config:cache php artisan migrate`
>
> `php artisan passport:install`
>
> `php artisan passport:client --personal`

Then my project works smoothly but problem is because i have to run
php artisan passport:install always then it generate keys again then current users have to logout to proceed further.
if i remove php artisan passport:install from these commands then it generate an error keys on found

Composer.json:

```
    {
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "barryvdh/laravel-cors": "^0.11.3",
            "bosnadev/repositories": " 0.*",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
            "laravel/passport": "^7.2",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
            "laravelcollective/html": "^5.7",
            "orangehill/iseed": "^2.6",
            "spatie/laravel-menu": "^3.3",
            "spatie/laravel-permission": "^2.32"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
            "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0",
            "user11001/eloquent-model-generator": "^2.0",
            "xethron/migrations-generator": "^2.0"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Error in log file if php artisan install:passport is not there:

> ```
> local.ERROR: Key path "/public_html/releases/1556096621/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or  is not readable {"userId":1,"exception":"[object]
> (LogicException(code: 0): Key path \"file:///folderName/public_html/releases/1556096621/storage/oauth-private.key\" does not exist or is not readable at
> /home/folderName/public_html/shared/vendor/league/oauth2-server/src/CryptKey.php:48)
> ```

Comment: Can you show your composer.json file?

Comment: i have update my question please see composer.json file @PrafullaKumarSahu

Comment: Have you checked your laravel.log file, if there is any error logged?

Comment: yes whenever code is auto deploy it generate an error keys not found and i have to run php artisan passport:install again but after it already login users have to logout

Comment: what is the error you are getting, can you post here?

Comment: I think it is with the `"post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"]`

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu update my question post error also

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu should i remove this command?

Comment: @hu7sy yes you can remove any comment, if you want to.

Comment: @hu7sy check https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/418 thread, it will give you better idea on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> passport:install command. This command will create the encryption keys
>   needed to generate secure access tokens. In addition, the command will
>   create "personal access" and "password grant" clients which will be
>   used to generate access tokens:

Passport generates these keys from your APP_KEY in .env . After composer install this key is changed, so existing keys generated by passport won't work: `local.ERROR: Key path "/public_html/releases/1556096621/storage/oauth-private.key" does not exist or is not readable`. Because it is generated with the old APP_KEY

Comment: so what should be solution?

Comment: I think it was the problem with permissions, read this thread https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/418